# Unable to display Xib that I added to my library. How to access that library's bundle?

Tags: ios, ipad, static-libraries, nsbundle

Here is what I'm doing:

```
NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
UIWindow *win = [windows objectAtIndex:0];
UIViewController *root_vc = [win rootViewController];
V *v = [[V alloc] initWithNibName: @"V" bundle:nil];
[win addSubview: v.view];
```

The problem is that I get an error indicating that the app that's using the library cannot find the V.xib in the main (app's) bundle.

So... how can I access the library's bundle?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the V.xib file does exist and has been added to your project, it is possible that you somehow don't have your build set up to copy that resource into the bundle.

If you are using Xcode 4, click on the project at the top of the project navigator. Select the appropriate target on the left and then click on the "Build Phases" tab to see how that target is building. There should be a "Copy Bundle Resources" section and if you expand it you should see your XIB file included. If it is not, drag the file from the project navigator to the list under the Copy Bundle Resources build phase.

Comment: I found out what the problem is... Apparently if a xib is in a library (.a in this case), the usual mechanism for loading it will not work. A much more complicated mechanism is required.